# Скрипт в статье

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Задача запустить скрипт генератора на определенной странице. Скрипт будет обращаться через `ajax` запрос к файлу `php`, последний будет выполнять функцию генерирования. `CMS WP`. Добавил скрип для работы с `php`  в статье.

Ничего лучше не придумал, как вставить этот скрипт `(JS)` в обычную статью.

Возникают седлающие проблемы:

1) `url:'get_template_directory_uri() .' + 'generator.php'`. Пробовал и без точки. Не находит файл, образуется директория которой нет ..generator/wp-content/.. . generator'а на том уровне нет и в помине. Сработало только `url: "../wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/generator.php`"

2) У generator.php такие же проблемы как и у скрипта в статье, такой `../wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/adept-page.zip` и такой `http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/adept-page.zip` и `get_template_directory_uri()` .+ 'generator.php'` не срабатывают вообще.

Вопросы:

1) Почему не сработал пути в статье и генераторе? Как правильно прописать там и там?

2) Есть ли более правильные реализации? Может есть модуль который позволяет вывести просто `html` документ?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#generatorFormButton").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "../wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/generator.php",
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
      });
    })
</script>
```

```html
<?PHP
  if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //если пришел не пустой POST
    $file = "http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/adept-page.zip";
    //создай переменную $file
    $stream;
    //$stream - поток
    //--------------------------------------------TOP
    $temp = fopen("http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/lib/standart/top.txt", "r");
    $stream = fread($temp, 999);
    //--------------------------------------------TOP
    if ($_POST['bootstrap'] === 'Yes') {
      $temp = "http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/lib/framework/bootstrap-top.txt", "r");
      $stream .= fread($temp, 999);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------CENTER
    $temp = fopen("http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/lib/standart/center.txt", "r");
    $stream .= fread($temp, 999);
    //--------------------------------------------CENTER
    if ($_POST['jquery'] === 'Yes') {
      $file = fopen("http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/lib/js/jquery.txt", "r");
      $stream .= fread($file, 999);
    }
    if ($_POST['bootstrap'] === 'Yes') {
      $temp = fopen("http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/lib/framework/bootstrap-bottom.txt", "r");
      $stream .= fread($temp, 999);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------BOTTOM
    $temp = fopen("http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/lib/standart/bottom.txt", "r");
    $stream .= fread($temp, 999);
    //--------------------------------------------BOTTOM
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open('http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/adept-page.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
    if ($res == TRUE) {
      $zip->addFromString('http://page-builder.net/wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/index.html', $stream);
      $zip->close();
    }
}
else {
  $file = "../wp-content/themes/pagebuilder/adept-page.zip";
  //создай переменную $file
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    unlink($file);
  }
  //если $file уже есть - удали ее
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, что функция `get_template_directory_uri()` не выводит слэш на конце uri, правильный вывод uri в php выглядел бы так:

```
$file = get_template_directory_uri() . '/adept-page.zip';
```

Я никогда не работал с WordPress, но предполагаю, что чтобы функция `get_template_directory_uri()` заработала в подключаемом вами php файле - нужно инклудить определённые файлы WordPress, отвечающие за эту функцию

а в статье как я понял вы пытаетесь совместить js и php, правильный запрос (если в статье WordPress конечно же можно использовать php, в чём я не могу быть уверен) выглядел бы так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#generatorFormButton").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/generator.php'; ?>,
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json'
  });
})
</script>
```